# How do I delete/clean Kafka queued messages without deleting Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way to delete queue messages without deleting Kafka topics?
I want to delete queue messages when activating the consumer.

I know there are several ways like:

1. Resetting retention time

   `$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic MyTopic --config retention.ms=1000`
2. Deleting kafka files

   `$ rm -rf /data/kafka-logs/<topic/Partition_name>`

Comment: The retention time trick you mention first is much better. The second way causes issues for replicated topics and makes the metadata for the topic inconsistent with reality. Note that the offset number won't go back to zero.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In 0.11 or higher you can run the `bin/kafka-delete-records.sh` command to mark messages for deletion.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-delete-records.sh

For example, publish 100 messages

```bash
seq 100 | ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic mytest
```

then delete 90 of those 100 messages with the new `kafka-delete-records.sh` 
command line tool

```bash
./bin/kafka-delete-records.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --offset-json-file ./offsetfile.json
```

where `offsetfile.json` contains

```json
 {"partitions": [{"topic": "mytest", "partition": 0, "offset": 90}], "version":1 }
```

and then consume the messages from the beginning to verify that 90 of the 100 messages are indeed marked as deleted.

```bash
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytest --from-beginning
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: Thanks Hans for the reply! It's very close to what I've been wanting.
Do you know by any chance if I can delete all the offset without knowing how much messages are queuing?
Would I be able to do this by editing the json?

Comment: Yes you can delete all messages. Also you could skip using this tool, and look at the source code and write your own program that directly call the same API to delete records before any given offset (including the latest offset) or you could lookup offsets by time stamp to delete all records before a particular time. The API this tool uses should be better documented in Kafka 1.0 which is out in Oct 2017

Comment: I've found that 
{"partitions":
 [{
     "topic": "test",
     "partition": 0,
     "offset": -1
 }],
 "version":1
}
can clear all the messages in the topic.  
The next problem I have is that this deletes the same topic of a different group.   
For example if topic "mytest" was in cosumer group "group1" and "group2" was watching topic "mytest", the tool will delete all of the messages in both groups.  
Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: There is only one shared commit log in Kafka so if you delete the messages they are gone for everyone independently from any consumer groups. If you just want to change one consumer groups offsets to skip over messages but leave them for other consumers then use bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --reset-offsets. See KIP-122 details here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It helps a lot. Is there any way to delete a range of messages in between the beginning and the end of the queue. Suppose my messages go from 0 to 100, I'd like to mark for deletion the messages 89 and 90. Thank you!

Comment: No that is not possible in Kafka. Kafka has a core property which is that it is an immutable commit log and allowing arbitrary range deletion would make it not so immutable.

Comment: I suppose if you knew in advance that you wanted to allow deletion of records then you could create the topic as a compacted topic which allows deletion of records through the use of “tombstone” messages (keyed messages with “null” values).

Answer (score 28):

To delete all messages in a specific topic, you can run `kafka-delete-records.sh`

For example, I have a topic called **`test`**, which has **4** `partitions`.

Create a `Json` file , for example `j.json`:

```json
{

"partitions": [

    {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 0,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 1,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 2,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 3,

        "offset": -1

    }

],

"version": 1

}
```

now delete all messages by this command :

```bash
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.1.1/bin/kafdelete-records --bootstrap-server 192.168.XX.XX:9092 --offset-json-file j.json
```

After executing the command, this message will be displayed

```bash
Records delete operation completed:
partition: test-0   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-1   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-2   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-3   low_watermark: 7
```