# Apache Kafka delete content

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using Apache Kafka and the application is using spring Kafka for the interaction. Currently we have topic and lot of message yet to be consumed. But we would like to delete all the content of the current queue , is there any straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete/clean Kafka queued messages without deleting Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209666/how-do-i-delete-clean-kafka-queued-messages-without-deleting-topic)

Comment: If you alter the topic, you can would set the retention really low, then it'll start to drop old events. Set it back to a high amount when you start to produce

Comment: Thanks it worked